# Get Bean instead of List object using Jdbctemplate and Rowmapping

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to fetch a result set and cast it to the Bean. Its not working. But then I tried to cast to List of beans, and it works. Can any one tell me how can I directly get a Bean object using Jdbctemplate and Rowmapping.

Here is my code.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM BB.Employeeswhere " +
            "BBEmpPK = ? ";

List<EmployeeDto> deals = (List<EmployeeDto>) getJdbcTemplate().query(
            sql,
            new Object[] {empId},
            new RowMapper<EmployeeDto>() {
                public EmployeeDtomapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    EmployeeDto d = new EmployeeDto();
                    d.setEmpName(rs.getString(2));                     
                    return d;
                }
            });
```

Ideally this should return only one row. Any ideas?

If there is any other solution without row mapper, that will be even good. Because in the table, I have 50+ columns, so it would be difficult to create a Bean with those fields

Comment: Why can't you just use `queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {empId}, String.class)` since you only get values from a single column `rs.getString(2)`?

Comment: Got it Yoshua. Please put that in answer. Will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need a single row and single column it is easy to just use:
`String userName = jdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {empId}, String.class);`

If you want more than 1 row and a single column you can use:
`List<String> userNames = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, new Object[] {empId}, String.class);`

---

Side Note:
Your implementation should've been this if you wanted it to work:

```
List<EmployeeDto> deals = jdbcTemplate.query(
    sql,
    new Object[] {empId},
    new RowMapper<EmployeeDto>() {
      public EmployeeDto mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        EmployeeDto d = new EmployeeDto();
        d.setName(rs.getString(2));
        return d;
      }
});
```